# Cakephp sharing auth between two applications

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2, authentication

Is there an easy way to share login information between two cakephp apps on the same domain?

Basically, MainApp has a full fledged user management suite, and I just want SecondaryApp to know if a visitor is logged in or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure both applications are configured to handle the session the same way. In other words, we want both apps to read from the same cookie and we need both apps to look in the same location for that cookie.

```
//app\config\core.php for both apps
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php'); //cookie path
Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'app_name'); //cookie name
```

In your MainApp, wherever you do the Authentication, set a session variable indicating the user has logged in.

```
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
```

Then in SecondaryApp you can read the session variables and act accordingly. I suppose typically you would ask to user to login.

```
function beforefilter(){
    if(!$this->Session->read('isLoggedIn')) {
        die("Please <a href='/users/login'>Login</a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: of course! Although is there a  $this->Session->write?  I'm not seeing one in the cakephp book

Comment: yes there is a $this->Session->write(), im guessing eSentrik is using $_SESSION for the other app.