# same cakephp session for multiple domains pointing to same directory

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I'm trying to do domain mapping on cakephp.. Now, I have my test site now pointing to my CakePHP site (cname) and it is now able to display the page fine..

However, if I'm logged in to *original.com* and then open *testsite.com* (the site I have mapped to original.com), the latter is not logged in though they're pointing to the same site (or same directory).

This is similar to [share session across multiple domains with the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746351/share-session-across-multiple-domains-with-the-same-app) only that mine is not really having two domains on my server but one domain only and another **mapped domain** (from another person)

How do I fix this issue? I'm using CakePHP 2.4.3..

Answer (score 0):

You can't share sessions between two domain for security.

But you can authenticate the user in two domains when the user sign in, like Google does.

At the controller you sigin the user, you can redirect two another domain with token security and then verify is valid. Look the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?hl=pt-BR&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail&service=mail

Google add a session then redirect's you where you want.

You can also try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022189/4289379